# SVN Merging oddities

Tags: svn

The team that I work for has been using SVN to keep the project that we're working on clean, that way we have our own working copies and can then just merge in the changes that we make to trunk as necessary, keeping our local branches in sync with the trunk.  Recently, a change was made to the trunk, and when I attempted to merge it into my own branch, which had been the same as the trunk up to that point, it wouldn't pick up the changes.  I attempted to check out a fresh copy of my own branch and merge it in again, but the files that were changed didn't get updated on my branch.  What's really odd, is that it did pick up some file changes, but they weren't any that had been made to the trunk.

Has anyone had a problem similar to this, and if so, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: Maybe consider using Mercurial (http://mercurial.selenic.com/) as source control; merging is a dream compared to SVN

Answer (score 2):

Pls have a look at svn:mergeinfo of that file to check whether the svn think that changes have already be merged from trunk to branch.